# How to create a container (ion-list) whose height reacts with device size in Ionic 2?

Tags: css, ionic-framework, ionic2

I have an `overflow: scroll` `ion-list` of `ion-button` that must never exceed the space from the top of the list to the start of the tab bar. Otherwise it will scroll the `ion-content` background instead. See attached screen shot. 
[image: when on top of the list]
[image: when scrolled down]
I made a demo app here: https://github.com/kamok/ionic-reactive-content-height. To see it, do `npm install` and `ionic serve`.

Basically, the `ion-list` in that app should `overflow:scroll`, but its height must be just less than the distance from top of `ion-list` NOT `100vh` to bottom of the tab bar. Note, that you CAN theoretically use something like `70vh` and it will fit for most devices but that leaves a empty white space which I don't want.

Comment: You should calculate the height you want your list to be. Have you also seen the ion-scroll element ?

Comment: take a look at flexbox, that is your best bet https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/